# How does He-Man turn back into Prince Adam?

Tags: he-man

We've all seen, once per episode, Prince Adam hold his sword in the air, shout

> "***By the power of Greyskull***"

and he and his cat getting transformed into the hulking skeleton-fighting duo, "He-Man" and "Battle-Cat" in a spectacular lightning-filled ritual, which the cartoon makes quite a big deal about showing us.

But then in the epilogue, they are once again back as Adam and Cringer, (ready for the next episode I suppose) with no mention of how they turned back.

**Did any episode ever reveal how this is done?**

Comment: The question brought back some old feelings..

Comment: +1 for spectacular lightning-filled ritual.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

He says "**Let the power return**". There is a video available on Youtube.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what episode(s) this scene appeared in.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson that'd be http://he-man.wikia.com/wiki/The_Problem_with_Power

Answer (score 4):

This was also shown to be how he transformed back in the 2002 series, and in the comics.

[image]

You can see him using it in the 2002 series here:

Go to 10:40 to see the transformation.

It should also be noted that instances of enough raw energy or magical force being thrown at him directly *have* on rare occasion seemed to "knock" him out of his transformed state. This too can be seen in the 2002 series.

Go to 16:00 - 16:55 to see the full effect. Even the sorceress knows it can happen, as she yells out  "He-Man, *no!* You **must not** challenge the power of the Stone!" So this would indicate there *are* some unforeseen magical conditions which can change him back without him willing it.

Another example of this would be in the 1980s cartoon, when he travels to Orko's dimension, Trolla, as He-Man, but is reverted back to Prince Adam as he steps out of the gate. He was unable to change back, even with the sword. After seeing Orko's magic work flawlessly and how the normal laws of physics seemed in opposition in that realm, it was later deduced by Cringer that "everything is backwards here!", so Adam had to recite his incantation *backwards* in order to utilize his full powers.... though why that didn't make him the *weakest* man in the Universe is beyond me.

Comment: Videos are dead

Answer (score 3):

In *[Masters of the Universe: Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masters_of_the_Universe:_Revelation)*, aired on Netflix in 2021, He-Man turns to Prince Adam by raising the sword of power and saying

> "Let the power return!"